# Unstacking multiple columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pivot-table, matlab-table

How do I unstack a data in matlab? The `unstack` for tables only allows me to do it for one column, and does not seem to be able to do a Multi Index solution as available in Python.

I was hoping to convert this:

[image: Raw Table]

into  this:

[image]

in Matlab.

Here is code to produce the initial table `T`:

```
Col1 = [1,2,4,1,3,1,2,3,4].';
Col2 = {'A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'}.';
Col3 = [0.48,0.78,0.58,0.01,0.53,0.26,0.93,0.69,0.45].';
Col4 = [0.95,0.29,0.90,0.72,0.07,0.23,0.81,0.22,0.88].';

T = table( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `unstack` function by specifying more than one variable for the 2nd input

```
Col1 = [1,2,4,1,3,1,2,3,4].';
Col2 = {'A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'}.';
Col3 = [0.48,0.78,0.58,0.01,0.53,0.26,0.93,0.69,0.45].';
Col4 = [0.95,0.29,0.90,0.72,0.07,0.23,0.81,0.22,0.88].';

T = table( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 );

tUnstack = unstack( T, {'Col3','Col4'}, 'Col2'  );
```

Output:

[image: unstacked table]

Note that, in MATLAB, you cannot have multiple header rows in a table. The `unstack` function concatenates header names (as shown above) for multiple categories, or can take an additional `'NewDataVariableNames'` argument if you wish to specify them.

If you needed multiple header rows, you would have to parse out the headers and store the new data in a cell array.